# Unable to create AVD in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

[image]

I tried to play around with the setting and looked through all the options but the "OK" button isn't enabled for me to complete the process. Any idea?

**Update**: The OK button is now enabled but after filling out everything and I press the OK, I receive a different error in the console:

> [2013-07-22 11:04:45 - SDK Manager] Error: null]

**Access issue**: [Android SDK AVD Error:null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162788/android-sdk-avd-errornull)

Comment: You have to specify all the options here, this includes the Front and Back camera etc.

Comment: You have no system images installed...possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488419/unable-to-create-android-virtual-device

Comment: @RobinChander Thanks! Why don't you answer it so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CPU/ABI` combobox is greyed out. Looks like you don't have system image required for this configuration.

Comment: I downloaded the package but now the OK button is enabled but When I click OK, Eclipse says the following error in console: `[2013-07-22 11:04:45 - SDK Manager] Error: null]`

Comment: Restart your eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem whit RAM, set 512 and VM Heap to 16. And the android emulator will work.
The virtualization in Windows doesn't support 1024M RAM.

Or you cand change the config file:

```
 avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
 hw.sdCard=no
 hw.device.manufacturer=Google
 hw.mainKeys=yes
 hw.lcd.density=320
 hw.accelerometer=yes
 hw.dPad=yes
 hw.cpu.arch=arm
 skin.name=720x1280
 abi.type=armeabi
 hw.device.hash=-708107041
 hw.trackBall=no
 hw.device.name=Galaxy Nexus
 hw.camera.back=emulated
 hw.sensors.proximity=yes
 hw.battery=yes
 disk.dataPartition.size=200M
 image.sysdir.1=platforms\android-10\images\
 hw.audioInput=yes
 hw.sensors.orientation=yes
 hw.camera.front=emulated
 hw.gps=yes
 skin.dynamic=yes
 skin.path=720x1280
 hw.keyboard=yes
 vm.heapSize=128
 hw.ramSize=1024mb
```

Cheers,

Comment: I downloaded the package but now the OK button is enabled but When I click OK, Eclipse says the following error in console: `[2013-07-22 11:04:45 - SDK Manager] Error: null]`

Answer (score 1):

Change the API target or install compatible system image. Use SDK manager and select android 4.0 api 14  :

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html

Comment: I downloaded the package but now the OK button is enabled but When I click OK, Eclipse says the following error in console: `[2013-07-22 11:04:45 - SDK Manager] Error: null]`

Comment: Try to select a different CPU if you can and set the RAM size to 512

Comment: I was able to create the AVD but I do not see it in the list to emulate :(